# Bootstrap3 navbar-collapse does not appear using cakephp

Tags: html, css, cakephp, bootstrap-modal, navigationbar

I have started working with cakephp frame work a month ago. I have trouble in making a mobile responsive navigation bar. i used the following Bootstrap with Cake:
https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/round-about/

The problem is that navbar-collapse does not show when it is clicked.

The following are related ctp files:

default.ctp

```
<?php$cakeDescription = 'BuySellSFSU';?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?= $this->Html->charset() ?>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>
    <?= $cakeDescription ?>:
    <?= $this->fetch('title') ?>
</title>
<?= $this->Html->meta('icon') ?>

<?= $this->Html->css('bootstrap.css') ?>
<?= $this->Html->css('bootstrap.min.css') ?>
<?= $this->Html->css('round-about.css') ?>
<?= $this->Html->script('bootstrap.js') ?>
<?= $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min.js') ?>
<?= $this->Html->script('jquery.js') ?>
<?= $this->Html->script('custom.js') ?>

<?= $this->fetch('meta') ?>
<?= $this->fetch('css') ?>
<?= $this->fetch('script') ?>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Navigation -->
<?= $this->element('header') ?>

<div id="content" class="container">

   <?= $this->Flash->render() ?>
   <?= $this->fetch('content') ?>

   <hr>
   <!-- Footer -->
   <?= $this->element('footer') ?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

header.ctp

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BuySellStuffs</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link('About', array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'home', 'full_base'=>true)); ?>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

The Problem aka headache lol

[image]

Thanks for the help, really appreciate it. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to load the jquery before bootstrap and remove the bootstrap.min (css and js)

```
<?= $this->Html->script('custom.js') ?>
<?= $this->Html->script('jquery.js') ?>
<?= $this->Html->script('bootstrap.js') ?>
<?= $this->Html->css('bootstrap.css') ?>
<?= $this->Html->css('round-about.css') ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

change the bootstrap.min.js and jquery.js order, do not include both bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.js, use only one.

Load Jquery Before Bootstrap js:

```
<?= $this->Html->script('jquery.js') ?>
<?= $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min.js') ?>
```